# Deserializing trival array in WCF results in empty collection

Tags: wcf

I have a problem with recieving any kind of array from remote WCF service. Even the most trival example with array of string is returning empty collection:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IArrayService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string[] getArrayStr();
}
```

SOAP response captured by Wireshark:

```
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
 <soap11env:Body>
  <tns:getArrayStrResponse>
   <tns:getArrayStrResult>
    <tns:string>ASD</tns:string>
    <tns:string>ASD</tns:string>
    <tns:string>ASD</tns:string>
   </tns:getArrayStrResult>
  </tns:getArrayStrResponse>
 </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

Result is empty:

```
var result = client.getArrayStr();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That response is not empty it has array with 3 values, what do you mean by empty collection?

Comment: This SOAP response was captured by Wireshark. From code in Visual Studio debugger, result is empty.